# delphi 10.1 fdconnection libmysql.dll

Tags: mysql, delphi, firedac

I would like to get or reach the line **DLL = C:\mysql\bin\libmysql.dll** from the application. The list below is copied from the FireDAC-connector info. But in what variable, object or "Class" can I find this information and be able to show that path c:\mysql\bin in my application?

```
================================
Connection definition parameters
================================
DriverID=MySQL
================================
FireDAC info
================================
Tool = RAD Studio 10.1 Berlin
FireDAC = 15.0.1 (Build 86746)
Platform = Windows 32 bit
Defines = FireDAC_NOLOCALE_META;FireDAC_MONITOR
================================
Client info
================================
Loading driver MySQL ...
DLL = C:\mysql\bin\libmysql.dll
Client version = 323520000
================================
Session info
================================
Current catalog = 
Current schema = 
Server info = 3.23.52-nt
Client info = 3.23.52
Characterset name = 
Host info = localhost via TCP/IP
Name modes = CILCT
SSL Cipher =
```

Comment: Have you tried dbl-clicking your FDConnection component?  The pop-up should tell you everything you need to know ( and maybe adjust) about your connection.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much MartynA for you comment. That helped me. I just clicked the "help" button on the FDConnection component and it showed me to the websitewhere I found the answer. The info about where the acutal libmySQL.dll is stored in a ini-file called FDDrivers.ini:

C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\FireDAC\FDDrivers.ini.

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Configuring_Drivers_(FireDAC)

Then in the file: 
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\FireDAC\FDDrivers.ini.
The lines may be changed pointing to a chosen libMySQL.dll
There are several libMySQL.dll files in my PC and it seemes very confusing. Especially because they are different versions of libMySQL and I need to use the right version wich is dated 2008 august 14. Therefore I have chosen to rename the dll file to libMySQL_20020814.dll to get some control over what's often called the "libMySQL.dll nightmare".

I also have changed the info in the mentioned FDDrivers.ini file to:

```
[MySQL]
VendorLib=libMySQL_20020814.dll
```

The good result is that my Delphi application will now look only for excactly the file libMySQL_20020814.dll in the directory where my Delphi application.exe - file is located. And not be "bothered" by all the other libMySQL.dll files in my PC. They are indeed many, as this Microsoft Windows command line will show:

```
c:\>dir libMySQL.dll /s /b
```

There was also one important thing to comment:
To get contact with the correct dll-file which was chosen from the FDDrivers.ini file I had to restart the Delphi IDE application (Embarcadero RAD studio version 10.1 Berlin). I did not manage to update the reading of the FDDrivers.ini file without restarting the Delphi IDE application.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download 32bit and 64bit files zip from the website https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-c/
2. Unzip both files into separate folders.
3. Create the following folder structure somewhere on the disk, e.g. "C:\MySql_Library\32bit\" and "C:\MySql_Library\64bit\".
4. Copy the libmysql.dll files from the unzipped zip files to the corresponding folders (32bit libmysql.dll to "C:\MySql_Library\32bit\" and 64bit libmysql.dll to "C:\MySql_Library\64bit\").
   Do not copy these files anywhere else!
5. Now, in a 64-bit application, put the FDPhysMySQLDriverLink component on the form and in the VendorLib field enter the path to the 32-bit libmysql.dll files (e.g. "C:\MySql_Library\32bit\libmysql.dll").
6. Test the FDConnection connection in the IDE.
7. In the program code of the event, e.g. OnCreate, write the following code: "FDPhysMySQLDriverLink.VendorLib:= 'C:\MySql_Library\64bit\libmysql.dll'" and press F9. The program should work with the MySql database.

Important!
It works when the 64-bit libmysql.dll library is version 6.1.11 or less. It does not work in version 8.0.18 and 8.0.19. (Error: EFDException with message '[FireDAC][Phys][MySQL]-314 is shown)